# Codeigniter database issue on a Gandi server

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-2

I have a Codeigniter website on a Gandi server with simple hosting solution. I basically have a ssh access, but I don't need to take care of the server configuration and so on.

Today I got this error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

The last changes I made were two days ago, and everything was working fine, so I'm sure this is not related to a problem in the code or configuration. I double checked the data I use to connect to the database and they are correct, but again, I didn't make any change in the past two days so it would've been weird if that was the problem.

Looking around I've found that many people suggest as a solution to set these two values:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

to `FALSE`.
Changing the `pconnect` didn't do anything.
Putting the `db_debug` to false lets me avoid the error and it actually shows the website, but then all the queries don't work.

I've also read to change the mysql socket, but on Gandi I can't change it. By the way, if it can be of any help, it's set to:

```
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Trying to debug it, I've put this at the end of the database.php file:

```
echo 'Trying to connect to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect
  (
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

    echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . '--> Line: ' .__LINE__);
```

And it outputs this:

```
Trying to connect to database: database_name
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Filename: test/database.php

Line Number: 72
Cannot connect to the database because: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can you help me understand what's going on? If you need other settings from php.ini or other file I can post them.

Comment: .. have you spoken to Gandi support? If you've not changed any code and the database suddenly isn't working I doubt it's something you can fix.

Comment: yes, but they still didn't reply and I fear that the issue is related to some server update and there is a compatibility issue with Codeigniter, so that I will have to make changes anyway, and I wanted to understand what could might be causing it